# C++ can't define virtual function OUTSIDE classes and header file

Tags: c++

As function name had been already declared in header file: `function.h` and header file were preloaded in OJ, I need to define `myAdd` in `main.cpp`, aka OUTSIDE classes. However, most tutorial I can find online about virtual function just define what the function should do INSIDE the class.This is header file:

```
#ifndef _FUNCTION_H_
#define _FUNCTION_H_
class abstractAdd
{
public:
    abstractAdd(){};
    ~abstractAdd(){};
    virtual int myAdd(int a, int b) = 0;

};

class Implement  : public abstractAdd
{
private:

public:
    Implement();
    ~Implement();

    int myAdd(int a,int b);

};
;

#endif
```

I have tried this in `main.cpp`

```
//include every libraries needed
#include "function.h"

int Implement::myAdd(int a,int b)
{
    int c=a+b;
    return c;

}

int main(){
    abstractAdd& ra = *new Implement();
    string input;
    while(getline(std::cin, input)){
        istringstream testcase(input);
        int a,b;
        testcase >> a;
        testcase >> b;
        cout << ra.myAdd(a,b) << endl;
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

But compiler said:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Implement::Implement()", referenced from:
      _main in cc3KANpW.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

How can I implement the function OUTSIDE classes and header files?

Comment: The linker error is about the **constructor**! You didn't implement *that*, and then probably tried to create an object. But you don't show the creation of the object. You figured it's immaterial. This is why it's important to verify your [mcve] reproduces the issue.

Comment: but I `new Implement()` in `int main`, didn't that count as construction?

Comment: @StoryTeller From the edit, it looks like you're right. Want to post an answer?

Comment: Sure, you edited it in now. My comment was about your *original* post, where that wasn't present.

Comment: Yes, `new Implement()` is main is a constructor invocation therefore you are getting an error becase you did not define the constructor being invoked. Also you never delete allocated memory so you have a memory leak. But if you did then you would also get an similar error for destructor `~Implement()` because it is not defined either.

Comment: This doesn't address the question, but names that begin with an underscore followed by a capital letter (`_FUNCTION_H_`) and names that contain two consecutive underscores are reserved for use by the implementation. Don't use them in your code.

Answer (score 3):

`new Implement()` will create an object. That entails calling the constructor. You declared a constructor `Implement();`, but didn't define it anywhere.

So the linker is complaining because it can't find the *constructor definition*.

If you simply wish to use the default constructor as a compiler would define it, you can declare it as follows:

```
Implement() = default;
```

It will be defaulted, and defined inline.

Same goes for `Implement`'s destructor as well.

---

As an aside, while your program is small and probably hosted, it still contains a leak. You allocate with `new` but don't `delete` the created object. In real production code, that will be unacceptable. You can simplify your code and rid you self of this concern by using a smart pointer:

```
std::unique_ptr<abstractAdd> ra = std::make_unique<Implement>();
```

Now that the object is disposed of correctly when the time comes, you should also make the destructor of `abstractAdd` virtual as well. Because now you are destroying an object polymorphically.

Comment: I change the constructor in `function.h` liked you suggested and it worked. But the problem is I can only run modified header file on my terminal since `function.h` in OJ was **fixed**. Maybe this is a problem with OJ or I have to define a new class to skip using `class Implement`?

Comment: @PHLin - I have no idea what OJ is. Some tutorial?

Comment: OJ stands for Online Judge system. OJs are popular in programming courses.

Comment: I have figured out how to define a constructor outside classes. Thanks.